# Running Power to My Garage

Tags: electrical, garage, underground

My spring project is to install electrical power to my new garage.
There is about 20 foot gap between my house and the garage.  The wiring will go underground.

In the garage, I am planning the following:

1. 2 overhead LED lights and 2 standard plugs.
   This will be for a projector and a (probable) electric, drop-down movie screen.
2. 5 internal plugs.  2 on each side of the garage.  1 for a gas heater with electrical fan.
3. 2 waterproof, external plugs.
4. 1 light switch for both the overhead LED lights.
5. 1 light switch for all the plugs.

I don't anticipate there being any heavy load on this circuit.  Mostly electrical tools for the yard (leaf blower, electric mower, etc. Occasionally, maybe an air compressor)

One future concern:
I expect to move my garage within 2 years so I would like the physical connection of the cable electrical to be plug-n-play, if possible.  That is, can the cable have some type of simple plug that I can easily remove or unplug at or near the entry-point in the garage, so I won't have to tear anything out when I move the garage.

Can anyone help me with my list of materials?

1. What kind of cable do I need.?
2. What is needed for the running the cable underground?  PVC Pipe?  meta pipe?  Other?
3. What type of box/connections do I need for the cable as it comes into the garage?
4. Anything else that I've not thought of?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In what way do you plan on moving the garage? Will it actually be jacked up and physically moved to a new location on the property (or on a different piece of property)? Yes, there simple, quick disconnects for wiring - they're called screws. You unscrew the wire, pull it out of the terminal that it was attached to, and off you go.

Comment: You're asking too much in one post here. Please take the [tour], then revise to ask just one specific question. We're not a discussion forum.

Comment: Depending on how far you are moving the garage, and how definite your plans are that that WILL be happening, it might make sense to have a large conduit box (or outside "pull box") where you store enough excess wire (now) that you won't need new wire (later) so you can just pull back the wires, extend new conduit from the pull box or old garage location to the new garage location, and re-install the wires.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Not a good idea. Problem is that storing wire in use coiled up will overheat. And if not in use then it is a separate set of wires and you haven't gained anything.

Comment: You can [edit] to narrow this question down.  It's best to start with a book on electrical.  That works better than Google and SE, because *they only answer questions, we can't tell you which questions to ask*.  The knowledge you need has a lot of depth, so a **well-rounded primer** is essential.   By the way, the warning about "don't coil wire" is correct but there are other ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Romex (non-metallic cable) normally refers to cable used inside, not outside. Outside cable and wires (including the underground feed between your house and garage) has to be able to handle water, which normal Romex can't.

But you don't really want to use cable anyway. You are much better off using individual wires run through a metal or PVC conduit. The depth you need to dig varies depending on cable by itself (deepest), PVC conduit (middle) or metal conduit (least). In most cases, you are also best off running aluminum wires instead of copper to save money. The size of the wires will depend on the specifics of your particular setup.

Detaching the cable or wires is trivial - just 4 screw connections in the subpanel. So don't worry about that.

The cable or wires will terminate in a subpanel. You will need a shutoff - but a main breaker in the subpanel takes care of that. That main breaker can be the same size as the breaker in your house panel connected to the feed to the garage or it can be larger. In fact, the subpanel can simply be an ordinary breaker panel, and bundles including a main breaker and several regular breakers are often the best deal. Get a big panel - extra spaces are not a problem but running out of spaces is a *big* problem.

Most, if not all (possible exclusion is hardwired lighting-only circuit), of the circuits will require GFCI protection. The easiest way to add GFCI is using GFCI breakers, but that is also the most expensive. GFCI receptacles are cheaper and often more convenient, but a GFCI receptacle can't be located up in the ceiling (e.g., for plug-in ceiling lights).

You will also need two ground rods connected to the subpanel. That is in addition to the ground wire going back to the house.

Comment: When moving the garage, get a concrete-encased electrode (Ufer ground) installed in the new foundation for the garage, which is better than ground rods as a grounding electrode. Those should be installed in any new concrete foundations, IMHO.